# Remove "Sign In"-marker from Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I develop an application with a very prominent Google Map. The "Sign In"-marker at the top right is distracting for the user, as my application has its own "Sign In".

Is it allowed and possible to remove that?!
Adding `disableDefaultUI: true` does not help.

[image: Sign in button]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because you include the Google Maps script with `signed_in=true` parameter.

Just replace :

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
```

or even remove the `sign_in` parameter.

Comment: that easy and obvious but I just didn't see it. Thanks!